# ListView and FrameLayout in ScrollView [BUG]

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a main Layout including 2 layout, one containing a FrameLayout with a Fragment inside. And the other one with a LinearLayout containing a ListView. This is how look my main layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include layout="@layout/map_layout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></include>
            <include layout="@layout/list_layout" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="6"></include>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The first Fragment contain a map and the second contain a custom ListView with its own listAdapter.

So here my problem, I know it's kind of triky to put a ListView in a ScrollView. But in my onCreateView of my ListFragment.java I put this :

```
        list.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

But the ListView keep catch the scroll. At a moment, the ScrollView bug and put the map and le list down of an infite ScrollView.

How can I do to make it work ?

Comment: You're trying to do something that the platform does not support, and it's a well limitation of it (IT DEFO IS NOT A BUG) and it's not working. And what is your question?

Comment: How can I do to make it work ?

Comment: You don't put a ScrollView inside a ListVIew, the platform does not support that. Try the CoordinatorLayout instead.

Comment: It's a ListView inside a ScrollView. But I will look How to use CoordinatorLayout.

Comment: ListView inside ScrollVIew or ScrollView inside ListView makes no difference. None of them were made to support nested scrolling and nested scrolling does not work with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find the solution of my problem.

I needed to extend my listView so there its only scrolled by the ScrollView. here the code I find :

Helper.java:

```
public class Helper {
    public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
        if (myListAdapter == null) {
        //do nothing return null
            return;
        }
    //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
  //setting listview item in adapter
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

and to implement it, you just need this line:

```
Helper.getListViewSize(myList);
```

I have found this solution here : http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html